# PHP Escape a string if it hasn't already been escaped with entities

Tags: php, string, html-entities

I'm using a 3rd party API that seems to return its data with the entity codes already in there. Such as `The Lion&#8217;s Pride`.

If I print the string as-is from the API it renders just fine in the browser (in the example above it would put in an apostrophe). However, I can't trust that the API will always use the entities in the future so I want to use something like `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` myself before I print it. The problem with this is that it will encode the ampersand in the entity code again and the end result will be `The Lion&amp;#8217;s Pride` in the HTML source which doesn't render anything user friendly.

How can I use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` only if it hasn't already been used on the string? Is there a built-in way to detect if entities are already present in the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one seems to be answering your actual question, so I will

> How can I use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars only if it hasn't already been used on the string? Is there a built-in way to detect if entities are already present in the string?

It's impossible. What if I'm making an educational post about HTML entities and I want to actually print this on the screen:

```
The Lion&amp;#8217;s Pride
```

... it would need to be encoded as...

```
The Lion&amp;amp&semi;&num;8217&semi;s Pride
```

But what if that was the actual string we wanted to print on the string ? ... and so on.

---

Bottom line is, you have to *know* what you've been given and work from there – which is where the advice from the other answers comes in – which is still just a workaround.

What if they give you double-encoded strings? What if they start wrapping the html-encoded strings in XML? And then wrap that in JSON? ... And then the JSON is converted to binary strings? the possibilities are endless.

It's not impossible for the API you depend on to suddenly switch the output type, but it's also a pretty big violation of the original contract with your users. To some extent, you have to put some trust in the API to do what it says it's going to do. Unit/Integration tests make up the rest of the trust.

**And because you could never write a program that works for *any* possible change they could make, it's senseless to try to anticipate *any* change at all.**

Answer (score 2):

Decode the string, then re-encode the entities. (Using [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php))

```
$string = htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($string));
```

https://eval.in/662095

Answer (score 1):

**There is NO WAY to do what you ask for!**

You must know what kind of data is the service giving back.

Anything else would be guessing.

---

Example:

what if the service is giving back `&amp;` **but is not escaping ?**

you would guess it **IS escaping** so you would wrongly interpret as `&` while the correct value is `&amp;`

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution, is first to decode all html entities/special chars from the original string, and then html encode the string again.

That way you will end up with a correctly encoded string, no matter if the original string was encoded or not.

Answer (score -2):

You also have the option of using htmlspecialchars_decode();

```
$string = htmlspecialchars_decode($string);
```

Answer (score -2):

It's already in htmlentities:

```
php > echo htmlentities('Hi&amp;mom', ENT_HTML5, ini_get('default_charset'), false);
Hi&amp;mom
php > echo htmlentities('Hi&amp;mom', ENT_HTML5, ini_get('default_charset'), true);
Hi&amp;amp&semi;mom
```

Just use the [optional]4th argument to NOT double-encode.